# How to use non-square padding for deconvnet in PyTorch

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

Thank you for you attention. I hopes to use `nn.ConvTranspose2d` to expand dimension of a tensor in PyTorch.(from (N,C,4,4) to (N,C,8,8)) However, I find that if I want to keep the kernel size to 3 and stride to 2. I need to set the padding to [[0,0],[0,0],[0,1],[0,1]](only one side to `H` and `W`), which is not a square.

I learnt that in tensorflow we can set the padding like `[[0,0],[0,0],[0,1],[0,1]]`, but in torch, the `padding` can only be a value for each dimension, which means the padding is on both sides.

So, I am wondering is there any way to do this in PyTorch?

Here's some code of details

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

a = torch.rand([100, 80, 4, 4])
a.shape
nn.ConvTranspose2d(80, 40, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=0)(a).shape
nn.ConvTranspose2d(80, 40, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)(a).shape
nn.ConvTranspose2d(80, 40, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=(0,1,0,1))(a).shape
```

```sh
>>> torch.Size([100, 80, 4, 4])
>>> torch.Size([100, 40, 9, 9])
>>> torch.Size([100, 40, 7, 7])
>>> RuntimeError: expected padding to be a single integer value or a list of 2 values to match the convolution dimensions, but got padding=[0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`F.pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.pad) from functional API.

```
b= nn.ConvTranspose2d(80, 40, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1)(a)
c = F.pad(b, (0,1,0,1),"constant", 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice reply. Just wondering if the result of using the `padding` in `nn.ConvTranspose2d` and then `pad` the same as not use the `padding` but remove one row. Plus, which one is more similar to the equivalence in TensorFlow? Thanks, Evan.

Comment: I do not think it should be same in both cases. Padding  will add "zeros" to row 8, while in the second case row 8 will not have zeros. My guess is that doing the padding as above should be equivalent to TensorFlow's padding, but I can not say for sure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think that's the right way. Maybe more appreciate way is to use `nn.ConvTranspose2d(80, 40, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, output_padding=1)`.